# User signup in REST API

Tags: php, web-services, restful-authentication

I have a PHP web application that I want to make accessible across multiple clients. So, I'm trying to make it more like an API. My question is: How would I handle the creation of new users using the API? If I have a URL like http://example.com/user/signup which takes new user details and creates a new user via a POST request, wouldn't it be a problem that people can misuse it and create fake users easily?

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend only allowing open id in the API, as it would be hard to implement bot preventing schemes into it (captcha ...)

anyway even open id isint that a great idea in the API are you sure you need registration available thru the API ?

Comment: I could not really understand what you meant by " as it would be hard to implement bot preventing schemes into it (captcha ...)". If I don't have registration in the API itself, how would I create new users across multiple clients, say an Android app for example...

Comment: but are you going to write the android apps etc ? if yes then registration should be done independantly of the API, if no then you should send some challenge to the app to verify that its a user not a bot. captcha would be good. but that is not wise IMHO , writing the registration for each client yourself would be more flexible and controlable

Comment: No, I'm not going to write the android apps etc. They will be written by someone else. I am developing only the API. CAPTCHA sounds like a good conceptual idea. I was thinking of using a token-based system very similar to Twitter (Twitter does not use for not registration though) where an app first asks for a token with some form of credential. However, what I'm looking for, is an example implementation of one of Android/iPhone's apps. If so many apps are already doing it, it makes more sense to think that there is already an established solution, which I cannot quite find.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use something like OAuth to authenticate access to your system from registered 'apps'. Then the clients can register for access and receive a token key and secret. Then they can use these things to create a request for an access token. Both parties sign the token using the secret and then they can use the encrypted access token to hit the API. Your server verifies the incoming token using the secret that only you and the authorized clients could have. Now it's secure.